# iOS contact form issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am new to using the iOS SDK and i am trying to make a basic contact form with a name, address, email etc... here's what i have done so far.

```
'- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailContoller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
[mailContoller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
NSString *email = @"******@gmail.com";
NSString *email1 = @"*******@hotmail.co.uk";
NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:email, email1, nil];
NSString *message = [[self myTextView]text];
[mailContoller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
[mailContoller setToRecipients:emailArray];
[mailContoller setSubject:@"IT WORKS!"];
[self presentViewController:mailContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  [[self myTextView] resignFirstResponder];
 }
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller                    didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
 {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

the problem i am having is that i do not know how to make multiple text fields that will be sent together via email.
thanks and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi,thanks for the reply and the problem is im still very new to xcode how would i concatenate the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concatenate the strings from the text fields.

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@",
     textField1.text, textField2.text, textField3.text];
```

Comment: hi,thanks for the reply and the problem is im still very new to xcode how would i concatenate the strings.

Comment: Hmmm. I showed you how to concatenate the strings in my code example. Please tick the checkmark and read a good basic text book on programming. Thanks.